# Magmi on the fly categories

Tags: magmi

I need to create a nested category menu structure, something like this:

- Product Groups

  - phones
  - cars
  - shoes
- Product Segments

  - cheap
  - expensive
- Product Types

  - electronic
  - old skool

A product can fit into any of these categories. It may exist in all for example, or maybe just 1 or 2.

Before I get to adding the products though, I'd like to create the category's. And there are about 100+ in total. Therefore, I am looking at using Magmi to do that.

However, I can only get Magmi running when I add products to 'new' categories at the same time. **Is it possible to tell Magmi** > OK, just create these empty categories > don't worry about the products for now... ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. Magmi can only create categories while creating or editing products.

I would recommend creating one single dummy product say "sku001" and simply create the categories on the fly while importing this dummy product. Later you can delete the product.

There are only 3 mandatory columns to create a product, they are:

"attribute_set","type","sku"

Your CSV can look something like this:

"Default","Simple","sku001",{all categories here in "category" column}

Comment: great - thanks for confirming what I expected.